# How to implement silverlight animation?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, animation

I want to implement silverlight animation in one of my xaml page. I have different shapes in my page. I want to fill colors with animation in the shapes. I want to implement different effects for different shapes for demo. Can someone give me idea of different effects of anumation? I am aware of Types of animation in silverlight. Double animation, Point animation etc.

Comment: A quick trip to the google machine will help you a lot here since your question is still pretty broad. Expression Blend is your new best friend. :) http://google.com/search?q=expression+blend+animation+effects